# gcc inline asm not compiling

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly

I'm currently trying to use the builtin `popcnt` in order to count the number of 1's in an array of `unsigned char`.

I had the function working with the regular `__builtin_popcount` but with some more aggressive speed requirements, I decided to go with the inline asm approach.

```
size_t popcnt_manual( unsigned char *bytes, size_t len ) {
    size_t i, cnt = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        __asm__(
                 "popcnt %0, %0    \n\t"
                 "add    %0, %1    \n\t"
                 : "+r" (cnt)
                 : "r"  (bytes[i]));
    }

    return cnt;
}
```

And the compiler keeps saying

> suffix or operands invalid for add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the syntax error in your code (`" "r"` -> `: "r"`), your problem is mismatched parameters.

Looking at the output from -S:

```
 add    rax, r8b
```

Since `cnt` is size_t and `bytes[i]` is a byte, this is what you'd expect.  Add requires them to be the same size.

Can I also suggest using builtins instead of inline asm?  It avoids problems like this (as well as many others).

---

> Is there any way to add up the result from popcnt without storing it off in a register first?

Umm.  That's actually an entirely different question.  The error you were asking about is due to mixing a byte and a size_t in a single `add` instruction.  It can be resolved by doing:

```
    __asm__(
             "popcnt %0, %0    \n\t"
             "add    %0, %1    \n\t"
             : "+r" (cnt)
             : "r"  ((size_t)bytes[i]));
```

I shouldn't encourage you to keep adding new questions (how will I get my karma points?), but looking at that website, the code he seems to be messing with is this:

```
uint32_t builtin_popcnt_unrolled_errata(const uint64_t* buf, int len) {
  assert(len % 4 == 0);
  int cnt[4];
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    cnt[i] = 0;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < len; i+=4) {
    cnt[0] += __builtin_popcountll(buf[i]);
    cnt[1] += __builtin_popcountll(buf[i+1]);
    cnt[2] += __builtin_popcountll(buf[i+2]);
    cnt[3] += __builtin_popcountll(buf[i+3]);
  }
  return cnt[0] + cnt[1] + cnt[2] + cnt[3];
}
```

He is explicitly using cnt[x] in an attempt to avoid the 'false dependency' problem of popcnt.

Using gcc 6.1 and compiling with `-m64 -O3 -march=native -mtune=native`, I'm seeing this as output:

```
.L14:
        popcnt  r11, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        add     rcx, 32
        add     edx, r11d
        popcnt  r11, QWORD PTR -24[rcx]
        add     eax, r11d
        popcnt  r11, QWORD PTR -16[rcx]
        add     r10d, r11d
        popcnt  r11, QWORD PTR -8[rcx]
        add     r9d, r11d
        cmp     rcx, r8
        jne     .L14
```

Which "storing it off in a register" are you referring to?

Comment: forgot to mention I started off with builtins but wanted something faster. Is there any way to add up the result from popcnt without storing it off in a register first? Got the idea from https://danluu.com/assembly-intrinsics/

Comment: thanks for the answer?  I must have been just confused with what the blog post was trying to say. Here are your karma points :)

Comment: The blog has no date on it, but it was written using 4.8.2.  That was a long time ago, so things may have changed.  This is another reason I recommend using builtins instead of inline.  builtins can improve over time, but if you write inline, you only get exactly what you write.  BTW, if performance is critical, using the 64bit popcnt is (probably) faster than repeated 8 bits.  You'll need to check the len and handle odd sizes, but I would try it and time it.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the input